# What is the component represented by two concentric circles in electrical schematics?

Tags: symbol

It does not seem to be a common symbol and I have suspicions it is a tube but there are only 2 contacts

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a quite common symbol and is usually used for coaxial connectors, such as a BNC connector. A great hint is the impedance callout of 50 ohms, and the "B" designator (though "B" is not really a commonly accepted standard reference designator for anything, to my knowledge).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this makes the most sense